# Model Posted Is Always Null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on an MVC4 application and I'm having a tough time with one form submittal. I've already got 4 other submission forms that work flawlessly, but this one simply refuses to work. Once you fill out the form, the object received in the controller is always filled with null values.

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(NcProgrammingIssue value)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.NcProgrammingIssues.Add(value);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(value);
    }
```

Model:

```
public partial class NcProgrammingIssue
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Employee { get; set; }
    public string JobNumber { get; set; }
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }
    public int OprSeq { get; set; }
    public string ResourceDescription { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeNum { get; set; }
    public string Severity { get; set; }
    public string LineNumbers { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public string SuggestedChange { get; set; }
    public string NcProgName { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model ShopConnectMVC.Models.ShopConnectEntities

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>NcProgrammingIssue</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NcProgrammingIssues.Date)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NcProgrammingIssues.Date)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NcProgrammingIssues.Date)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NcProgrammingIssues.Employee)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NcProgrammingIssues.Employee)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NcProgrammingIssues.Employee)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NcProgrammingIssues.JobNumber)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NcProgrammingIssues.JobNumber)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NcProgrammingIssues.JobNumber)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NcProgrammingIssues.PartNumber)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NcProgrammingIssues.PartNumber)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NcProgrammingIssues.PartNumber)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NcProgrammingIssues.OprSeq)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NcProgrammingIssues.OprSeq)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NcProgrammingIssues.OprSeq)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NcProgrammingIssues.ResourceDescription)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NcProgrammingIssues.ResourceDescription)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NcProgrammingIssues.ResourceDescription)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NcProgrammingIssues.EmployeeNum)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NcProgrammingIssues.EmployeeNum)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NcProgrammingIssues.EmployeeNum)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NcProgrammingIssues.NcProgName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NcProgrammingIssues.NcProgName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NcProgrammingIssues.NcProgName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NcProgrammingIssues.Severity)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NcProgrammingIssues.Severity)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NcProgrammingIssues.Severity)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NcProgrammingIssues.LineNumbers)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NcProgrammingIssues.LineNumbers)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NcProgrammingIssues.LineNumbers)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NcProgrammingIssues.Comment)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NcProgrammingIssues.Comment)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NcProgrammingIssues.Comment)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NcProgrammingIssues.SuggestedChange)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NcProgrammingIssues.SuggestedChange)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NcProgrammingIssues.SuggestedChange)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

The view is just the standard scaffold, but it refuses to work. The NcProgrammingIssue object passed to the controller is always populated with null/default values. This should be fairly simple, since the other 4 forms were completed in less than one day.

I checked for the standard stuff, like naming the Controller variable something unique, and making sure none of my properties contain keywords found in the Class name. All that stuff checks out, but I'm still stuck with the same issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue here is that the values you're posting are *prefixed* by `NcProgrammingIssues`. This is due to the fact that you're doing `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.NcProgrammingIssues.Employee)`.
If you take a minute and look at the posted values through your browser network-tab, you'll understand what I'm talking about.

The sollution to this should be fairly easy: Tell the `Action` that it should expect the prefix.

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Prefix="NcProgrammingIssues")]NcProgrammingIssue value){...}
```

Hope this helps

Edit: Small remark for how the modelbinder works: If it notices your method argument (in this case `value`) has the same name as the prefix, it'll automatically bind this as well. So in this case you theorethically *could* fix it by just renaming `value` into `NcProgrammingIssues`

Comment: Wow, thank you for this answer! Looking over the other forms, they all had an 's' after the variable names. I totally missed that one. Thanks a million!